# Как полностью отключить масштабирование сайта?

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Как полностью отключить масштабирование сайта? Будь то кнопки ctrl+колесико, или настройки браузера

Нужно это из-за бага анимации блока.. При масштабировании страницы блок становится не той формы, которую я задавал. Исправляется это только обновлением страницы. Но если опять масштабировать сайт, эта проблема снова возникнет. В общем не суть

Как полностью отключить возможность масштабирования сайта?

Comment: написав свой браузер? Я думаю, лучше просто исправить ошибку анимации.

Comment: @KoVadim эту ошибку, по видимому, невозможно исправить. Попробуйте масштабировать вот этот популярный сайт. Вы увидите неправильные пропорции анимированных элементов на логотипе. Обновите страницу - они станут нормальные. Масштабируйте сайт до нормальных размеров - и опять та же ошибка. 
https://daneden.me/animate/
Если такой сервис не смогу ее исправить, значит решения пока что нет. (в гугле я тоже не обнаружил)

Comment: в других браузерах анимация на этом сайте вообще не работает нормально. 

> Если такой сервис не смогу ее исправить, 

какой то малоизвестный сервис.

А если честно, то нормально масштабировала только опера - все по честному, с картинками. А другие браузеры просто увеличивали размер шрифта, а картинку оставляли предыдущих размеров. Может быть Вы наткнулись не на баг, а на, как утверждают браузеропостроители, задокументированную фичу.

Comment: Возможно вам может помочь `{zoom: reset;}`

Answer (score 1):

На десктопах кажется никак, а вот на мобильных устройствах можно так:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

Если повесить такой обработчик на отдельный элемент, то над ним (!) масштабирование Ctrl + прокрутка отменится:

```
rbrd.onwheel = function() {
    if(event.ctrlKey) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Не самый красивый, конечно, но рабочий способ: повесить его на **все** элементы страницы.

Comment: rbrd - это element, забыл подправить